# how to disable required on cancel selcted

Tags: javascript, php

i have two select dropdown one for selected rooms  and select cancel booking..

```
<div>Confirm:</div>
    <div>
        <select id="status" name="status" class="form-control" required>
            <option value="1">room2</option>
            <option value="2">rrom2</option>
        </select>
    </div>

 <div>Status:</div>
    <div>
        <select id="status" name="status" class="form-control" >
            <option value="1">Confirm booking</option>
            <option value="2">Cancel booking</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

now i want the cancel booking by selecting cancel and submit, but probelm is there first select is required, i want required only in confirm , how i can do this

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far

Comment: you can use jquery

Comment: how to do using jquery , give some idea.

Comment: use jquery on change event

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Add `select-room` and `booking-status` class in 2 selectbox so that detect it event. because you have same id status in 2 selectbox. please set unique id for each of the element in html.

```js
$(".booking-status").change(function(){ // use change event for select box of booking
  if($(this).val() == "2") {
     $(".select-room").removeAttr("required");
  } else {
     $(".select-room").attr("required","required");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Confirm:</div>
    <div>
        <select id="status1" name="status" class="form-control select-room" required>
            <option value="1">room2</option>
            <option value="2">rrom2</option>
        </select>
    </div>

 <div>Status:</div>
    <div> 
        <select id="status2" name="status" class="form-control booking-status" >
            <option value="1">Confirm booking</option>
            <option value="2">Cancel booking</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: the two elements have the same id

Comment: @RafaelShkembi thats why I have added class in 2 select box

Comment: Adding class doesn'

Comment: Adding class doesn't resolve the issue of using the same id multiple times.

Comment: adding class will definitely solve issue :) in case you have same id in html but you are not using it anywhere in jquery - it will not create any issue, otherwise it will - no doubt unique id for each element is needed for good practice - but if you will add different class to element and access that class in jquery it will create any issue

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure that id should be unique in an HTML page. You seemed to have used same id's for these two select boxes.

```
<div>Confirm:</div>
<div>
    <select id="room" name="room" class="form-control" required>
        <option value="1">room2</option>
        <option value="2">rrom2</option>
    </select>
</div>

 <div>Status:</div>
 <div>
    <select id="status" name="status" class="form-control" >
        <option value="1">Confirm booking</option>
        <option value="2">Cancel booking</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Now use the jQuery code:

```
$(function(){
   $("#status").on("change", function(){
     if($(this).val() == 2) {
       $("#room").attr("required", false);
     }  else {
       $("#room").attr("required", true);
     }
  });
});
```

Refer to this JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gx0s27s9/

Comment: You're welcome. Please up vote the answer and accept it if it solves your issue.